# Spring Boot | spring EL using with annotation attribute value to set any random value using properties

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-kafka, spring-el

I am using one existing spring boot annotation and want to set the attribute value dynamically using spring expression and want to have one constant value as a prefix,

**sample Code snippet**

```
@KafkaListener(topics="${topic.name}", groupId="#{'consumergroup' + (int)(java.lang.Math).random() }")
    public void consumerMethod(){
    
    }
```

I want to create a new consumer group for each new container using the above kind of implementation.

But I am facing the below exception.

> Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After
> parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the
> expression: 'lparen(()

kindly help me to either use *template spring EL* or any other way I can use to set dynamic consumer group id with the constant prefix.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added in my code snippet but missed to add here in question, can you please check now.

Comment: If any want to give a negative marks just because they don't understand kindly let me know I will correct those.

Comment: AFAIK you also need to prefix the static call with `T` so something like `(int) T(java.lang.Math).random()`. I don't think it would work otherwise.

Comment: See my also my answer.

Comment: @ArtemBilan working like a charm perfect one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
groupId="#{'consumergroup' + (100 * T(Math).random()).intValue() }"
```

1. There is no `cast` operator in SpEL. Just because it uses a `ConversionService` internally to convert from one type to another. I use `intValue()` any way because the result of `random()` is `Double` (not `double`) - SpEL does coercion into type wrappers for API convenience.
2. The `java.lang` is imported into SpEL context automatically. No need to add it for `Math` type.
3. `100 *`. See `Math.random()` JavaDocs: it returns the value between `0.0` and `1.0`. So, casting to `int` would always bring you only `0`. The casting doesn't do rounding.

Also see Spring Boot configuration properties feature where you can use random value for the `groupId`:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=consumergroup${random.int}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.random-values